# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')"

Tags: c#

I have the following classes inside my c# console application:-

```
public class SearchCriteria
    {
        public string field { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string logical_operator { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListInfo
    {
        public int row_count { get; set; }
        public int start_index { get; set; }
        public string sort_field { get; set; }
        public string sort_order { get; set; }
        public bool get_total_count { get; set; }
        public List<SearchCriteria> search_criteria { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public ListInfo list_info { get; set; }
    }
```

and when i tried to populate the Root object, as follow:-

```
                        Root root = new Root(){};
                        root.list_info = new ListInfo();
                        root.list_info.row_count = 1000;
                        root.list_info.start_index = 1;
                        root.list_info.sort_field="subject";
                        root.list_info.sort_order = "asc";
                        root.list_info.get_total_count = true;
                        root.list_info.search_criteria = new List<SearchCriteria>();
                        root.list_info.search_criteria[0].field = "last_updated_time";
                        root.list_info.search_criteria[0].condition = "between";
                        root.list_info.search_criteria[0].value = "$(last_30_days)";

                        root.list_info.search_criteria[1].field = config.GetSection("ServiceDesk").GetSection("field").Value;
                        root.list_info.search_criteria[1].condition = "is";
                        root.list_info.search_criteria[1].value = "yes";
                        root.list_info.search_criteria[1].logical_operator = "AND";
```

i got this error:-

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')"
```

on `root.list_info.search_criteria[0].field = "last_updated_time";`.. any advice?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski can you advice more on this?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i tried your code but got the same error on the `root.list_info.search_criteria[0] = new SearchCriteria();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **root.list_info.search_criteria** still empty, so there isn't items in this list.
You only should make

```
root.list_info.search_criteria.Add(new SearchCriteria());
```

Then it will works.